# meteor methods functions return is not working

Tags: javascript, reactjs, meteor, ecmascript-6

I am trying if my data is removed then show `return "removed successfully";` but it's not working also not removing the data. If I am not used function then data is removed but not getting any return result form call back

**Its working**

```
  Meteor.methods({
        removeFAV: function(userID, product_id) {
            Favorites.remove(
                { user_id: userID, product_id: product_id },
                { multi: true }
            );
        }
    });
```

**It's not working**

```
Meteor.methods({
        removeFAV: function(userID, product_id) {
           Favorites.remove(
                ({ user_id: userID, product_id: product_id }, { multi: true }),
                function(err) {
                    if (err) {
                        return err;
                    } else {
                        return "removed successfully";
                    }
                }
            );
        }
    });
```

Comment: Did my answer helped you?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Meteor `Mongo.Collection` is not a native Mongo Collection but a wrapper that integrates native Mongo calls into the Meteor environment.

See: https://docs.meteor.com/api/collections.html#Mongo-Collection

The `insert` `update` and `remove` methods have a specific blocking behavior unless you provide a callback:

> On the server, if you don’t provide a callback, then remove blocks until the database acknowledges the write and then returns the number of removed documents, or throws an exception if something went wrong.
>
> If you do provide a callback, remove returns immediately. Once the remove completes, the callback is called with a single error argument in the case of failure, or a second argument indicating the number of removed documents if the remove was successful.
>
> https://docs.meteor.com/api/collections.html#Mongo-Collection-remove

Since the blocking type call is automatically throwing en error, there is theoretically no need to explicitly handle the exception:

```
Meteor.methods({
    removeFAV: function(userID, product_id) {
        const removedDocs = Favorites.remove(
            { user_id: userID, product_id: product_id },
            { multi: true });
        // remove returns the number of docs being removed
        return `removed [${removedDocs}] document(s) successfully`
    }
});
```

Such a method will return in the callback of `Meteor.call` either the thrown error as first parameter or the result as second.

However, it also makes sense to handle the exception and let the method fail silently:

```
Meteor.methods({
    removeFAV: function(userID, product_id) {
        let removedDocs = 0
        try {
            // remove returns the number of docs being removed
            removedDocs = Favorites.remove(
             { user_id: userID, product_id: product_id },
             { multi: true });
        } catch (e) {
            // log error
            myErrorLog.log(e)
        } finally {
            return `removed [${removedDocs}] document(s) successfully`
        }
    }
});
```

This will never return an error to the client but logs the error on the server.